What is the difference in meaning between the two sentences?
What is the difference in meaning between the two sentences?
This new cheap vehicle "has" Toyota "crapping" in their pants.
This new cheap vehicle "has" Toyota "crap" in their pants.
Usually, in this kind of grammar, HAVE/HAS should be followed by "Base Verbs", shouldn't it? Could native speakers please explain it to me? Thank you.

This is actually tough to explain.  It's not a difference in HAVE but a difference in aspect of the participle and base form.  Causal HAVE (present tense) with base form of the verb has the sense of action as prospective task, and causal HAVE (present tense) with present participle has the sense of action as task-in-progress.  The kindergarten teacher has the students learning their ABCs,  "

Where "task" is very broadly construed to mean "what the person is made to do", even if the task is "to sweat bullets".   The new Toyota truck has Ford execs sweating bullets.

Nitpick: double-quotes are normally used to indicate direct speech.  To emphasise words, as here, it's usual to use bold, or italics, or underline.  (While capitalisation can also be used for emphasis, it's usually for very strong emphasis, such as to represent shouting; it's also used for acronyms and other abbreviations.)

@gidds - when you see typos or similar entry mistakes, just tap edit and fix.  (example, on the programming site its common a quetion forgets to tap "code style format" button. when you see that you just tap edit and fix, no need to talk about it!)

Why is this Q causing so much discussion?  OP, has is present tense, so it should be crapping which is present tense.

@TimR - regarding the #2 incorrect sentence, can you see a reading where it is subtly correct in some unusual situation? (I can't.) ; I don't see (or know!) what the "other" form is you describe in your second sentence outlining two possibilities, what would that be?  (PS this is not a rhetorical smart ass quewstion, I'm just too stupid to know and want you to explain!  :) TY)

@Fattie Yes, if the intended meaning is "on a regular basis" which  is one of the uses of the simple present.  The doctor has me do twenty push-ups every time I come into the office and he measures my BP before and after.

@TimR Yes, if the intended meaning is "on a regular basis"  Ah, my God, I did not see that at all!  (Perhaps the uncolloquial "their" threw me off .. "This new cheap vehicle has Toyota crap their pants".  Still, it sounds more like a not-one-event to me?  Cheap new vehicles have Toyota crap their pants.) Thanks !

@Fattie: You could also use the simple present in a video caption: "Lazy owner has pet collie fetch a Pabst Blue Ribbon from fridge."

You're right, this could be a headline: New cheap vehicle has Toyota crap their pants.  PS in the previous there's a typo (can't now edit) .. the uncolloquial "in" threw me off on this whole affair. ".. has Toyota crap their pants" yes, "has Toyota crap in their pants" sounds non-native.  @TimR

I keep typing simple present when I mean the base form. Sorry. Old habit from the days when the base form was called "the present infinitive".

I don't think much of the OP's example context, but so far as I'm concerned the same syntactic and semantic issues arise with...

1: Tom had Dick shout
2: Tom had Dick shouting

...which are both perfectly valid and carry the same basic meaning (Dick shouted because of something Tom said or did), but they carry different implications.
#1 implies that Tom explicitly requested / ordered Dick to shout. Perhaps Tom was inviting questions from the audience after giving a presentation, and asked Dick (at the back of the room) to speak up so everyone could hear.
#2 implies that Tom was doing something which as a side effect / consequence caused Dick to become so outraged that he started shouting. Perhaps Tom was giving a political speech that Dick violently objected to, so Dick started loudly shouting / heckling.
Note that it's perfectly possible for the continuous form #2 to be used even if Tom expects (and maybe even wants) Dick to do the stated action. Perhaps Tom is a standup comic, and he's making Dick laugh uncontrollably...

3: Comedian Tom had Dick (in the audience) rolling in the aisles

...but we can be pretty sure Tom didn't explicitly say anything like "Dick! I want you to roll in the aisles!", which would be conveyed by...

4: Comedian Tom had Dick (in the audience) roll in the aisles
(syntactically valid, but semantically "weird")


Usually in construction #1, the subject ("Tom", in my example) is a "conscious agent" (a person), because that subject manifests "volition / authority". So some people might reject the infinitive verb ("crap" in OP's example) because the subject is just a vehicle, which can't tell anyone what to do. But that's a matter of personal preference.

A sentence like The company’s new product had its competitors sweating means that during the time period being discussed, the company’s competitors were sweating and that the cause of their distress was the new product.
In general, to have someone X-ing means to be currently causing them to X. It is an idiomatic expression.
As in that example—where to sweat a thing means to be worried about it—the construction is often used with metaphors, as in

Her comedy routine had the audience rolling in the aisles.

Here to roll in the aisles means to laugh uncontrollably. The image is of being so convulsed with laughter as to fall from one’s seat in an auditorium and thrash on the floor. Another example is

Jane’s impertinence had her teacher seeing red.

Here, to see red means to be very angry. The image is that one’s anger causes the blood vessels in one’s eyes to dilate, thereby affecting one’s vision. One final example is
The politician was such a gifted speaker that he often had his audiences eating out of the palm of his hand.
This metaphor compares audience members to once-wild animals, now so tamed as to be willing to approach close enough to take food from one’s hand.

The second sentence is an incorrect formation of the first.  (I assume the quotes are just a form of emphasis, and should probably appear as italics).
Crap is a uncountable noun, making it singular, which doesn't go with the "has".
The meaning of the sentence would be "Toyota is very afraid of this new cheap vehicle".
Variations using a singular crap could be used, if you wanted to emphasize that the fear was brief, and they have since recovered.  "This new cheap vehicle made Toyota crap their pants, but they quickly realized that it was as unreliable as it was cheap often failing within days of purchase".

The word "crap" is unquestionably a verb in both OP's examples.
